# Applying CSS dynamically when message appears JSF + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf-2.2

I'm having a problem to apply dynamically a css in a component using JavaScript or jQuery. I tried some things as showing below.

This is my Component which I'm trying apply the CSS

```
<p:inputText id="txtUser" styleClass="form-control"
                                 value="#{registerMB.user.name}"
                                 disabled="#{registerMB.disabledUserDetailsBoolean}"
                                 requiredMessage="Por favor insira um Utilizador(NAME)."
                                 onblur="value=value.toUpperCase()">
                        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{registerMB.showUserDetails()}"
                                update="frmRegisterUser:accordion:results  frmRegisterUser:panelButton button"  />
                    </p:inputText>
```

This is the component I'm trying to catch the message:

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="false" closable="true" />
```

In the browser after compile the HTML I have this element

```
<div class="ui-messages-error ui-corner-all"><a href="#" class="ui-messages-close" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp();return false;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a><span class="ui-messages-error-icon"></span>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="ui-messages-error-summary">Nome do Solicitante inválido!</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm triyng apply the CSS **ui-state-error** on the component with id **txtUser** when the message **Nome do Solicitante inválido!** appears on the screen. I tried this code but I didn't have success. Follow my JQuery:

```
function checkName() {

   var txt = $(".ui-messages-error-summary" )[0].innerText;
   $(txt.replace(/^[ \t]+/gm, ''));

    if($(txt).is(':contains("Nome do Solicitante inválido!")')){
    $('#frmRegisterUser:accordion:txtUser').addClass('ui-state-error')
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your actual problem that you are trying to solve here? PrimeFaces already adds this to inputs when they are invalid

Comment: @Kukeltje I need to do this using jquery when I fire the event blur. You can sugest other solution but my priority is using Jquery.

Comment: Why??? Who told you it should be done with jquery? You have with 99% certainty an http://xyproblem.info here. And unfortunately for you, that is not something I want to spend my time on. Cheers...

Comment: Ok @Kukeltje don't spend your time.

Answer (score 0):

I did, I used the DOM and applied the CSS.

```
function checkName() {
   var txt;

   var inputElement = $(".ui-messages-error-summary" )
   if(inputElement[0] != null){
    txt = inputElement[0].innerText;

    if(txt.includes("Name")){
    var element = document.getElementById("frmRequestRegisterUser:accordion:txtUser")
    element.classList.add("ui-state-error");
    }

   }
}
```